# podman not working properly with YAML generated from k8s

Tags: podman

`podman play kube xxxxx.yaml`

It returns the error message:

```
Error: error encountered while bringing up pod xxxxxx-pod-0: error adding pod to state: name "xxxxxx-pod-0" is in use: pod already exists
```